# Amazon AWS OAuth2 example in .netcore

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement a simple OAuth2 authentication access for Web API's using .netcore 3.1.  I can't seem to find any examples of how to implement this.  Does anyone have any c# examples on how to do this or any good tutorials?

Thanks in advance, Richard

Comment: OAuth in general is very easy to do. Which Identity Provider are you using (Cognito, Google,Okta, Auth0, etc.)? Which OAuth grant type? Does the system have a  web browser (required for some grant types)? Since AWS is one of your tags, here is an article for Amazon Cognito: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-the-asp-net-core-identity-provider-preview-for-amazon-cognito/ AND http://snevsky.com/blog/dotnet-core-authentication-aws-cognito

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your reply!  I'm a complete newbie to all of this.  We have an aspnetcore web application connected to a DB.  Our use case is to add web api's so we can access that data e.g. add users / remove users, customers etc...We currently use Windows Identity but would like to move to AWS.  I did implement my own JWT local token based authentication, but our customers need OAuth2.  Am looking trying to implement Cognito at the moment but am getting strange error, but this is not OAuth2 is it? I'm guessing I we need code grant type and refresh token.  Will look at links. Thanks, R.

Comment: Before trying to tackle Cognito, learn the basics of OAuth. Here is an example that uses the CLI `curl` with Google OAuth. The basics are really simple: https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-version-2/

Comment: Brill.  I will do that now and let you know how that goes.....